# how to start VMWARE player 6 on Windows 7 from Windows .bat file

Tags: windows, vmware

I want VMWARE to start automatically when I restart Windows 7.
So, I want the command line for this in a .bat file that my Windows startup can call.

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed you mentioned what VMware Application you're using in question's subject.

VMware Player is now VMware Workstation Player.

I can find no topics related to this in 6.0 version, so I don't think it's possible. Anyway, you may try doing the following:

- Add vmplayer.exe to Startup Programs in start menu
- Register a scheduled task "On Startup" for vmplayer.exe
- Run vmplayer.exe from it's root folder via cmd, that would be something like

  C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmplayer.exe

If you're trying to start a virtual machine, you can do it by running the command above plus adding the "-x" parameter, as said **just in [Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/ws7_manual.pdf)** Documentation, page 486.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of bugs in the installer of VMWare player 6. You should swap these values in the Windows registry :

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\vmplayer.exe\shell\open
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\vmplayer.exe\shell\open\command

Then add this key :

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.vmx\OpenWithList\vmplayer.exe

Assuming your Virtual image is in C:\Users\stackoverflow\, your batch file should be similar to this :

```
start "" /low "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmplayer.exe" "C:\Users\stackoverflow\Win10.vmx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `open` verbs are correctly set in the registry (see @Doe Doe's post) you can just use:

```
start "path\to\my_vm.vmx"
```