# How to start virtual machine programmatically?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine

I have 2 Virtual Machines: Windows 10 and Ubuntu inside hosted in Windows 10.
How I can start these VMs from c# application?I.e. to boot OS etc.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Missing a lot of info: Virtual Box? VMWare? Which version? Have you searched? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949662/how-to-start-vmware-player-6-on-windows-7-from-windows-bat-file

Comment: Sorry, VMWare 12.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just call powershell commands from your C# code, and then actually manage your VMs with your powershell code.

Executing powershell in C#:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Powershell and VMs:

- http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/how-to-configure-vm-auto-start-powershell/
- VMWare https://communities.vmware.com/thread/449165